# Asking for ID in interview

Tags: hiring, process

I was contacted for customer service representative position in which they are using the telegram app to communicate via messenger no video chat and asking me to scan front and back of my drivers license as well as a utility bill for proof of residency and return a hire letter with my signature

Comment: I am voting to close as this is off-topic here. However, this is almost surely an identity theft scam. Please do not comply and continue seeking legitimate employment.

Answer (score 16):

This is almost certainly a scam. No company needs a scan of your drivers license in the first interview. Also no company will conduct an interview via Messenger - at the very least they will use voice. It's also a red flag that they contacted you first, and don't appear to have done any real evaluation of your ability to do the job.